# Content settings missing - chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I have two iPhone 6 devices, both with latest version of iOS and both with latest version of Google Chrome.

I've noticed a difference in the Content settings accessed by:

```
Chrome app (browser) > menu > settings > content settings
```

**However, on one of them there are 4 content settings:**

```
Block Pop-ups
Google Translate
Accept Cookies
Auto-Detect Encoding
```

**On the other one there are only two:**

```
Block Pop-ups
Google Translate
```

**Anyone have any idea why? Is there a setting somewhere I have overlooked which causes this to be different?**

The iPhone with only two settings also makes my web app fail, but I won't go into details, though I will say this is the only difference between the two devices.

**Also**

I have two iPads with the same issue - one with 4 items, one with 2 - also, the web app fails on iPad with only 2 items.

I don't have access to iOS debugging at the moment

Comment: I'm guessing these content settings are not shared via the google account across devices... have you tried turning on cookies on the one that does not work?

Comment: Thanks but nope, I've tried logged in and not and it makes no difference

Comment: Also, there's nowhere to turn cookies on in the one that doesn't work - hence only two items on the Content Settings